# How can accomplish this design using Recycler Views in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

[image]

How can I accomplish the above design using recycler view list adapter, prefarably in kotlin (Java is fine too).

I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish this without third party libraries, just using StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. This is just a `RecyclerView` with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` and two different `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` implementations.

1. Create a layout file that only contains one squared `ImageView` and create a RecyclerView.ViewHolder
2. Create a layout file that contains a wrapper that is the same size as the previous and contains 4 `ImageView` and create a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` for that one too

Then just map your Image collection into a list of these two types of viewholder and feed that to your recyclerview adapter